# How to use different model definitions for different database providers in sqlalchemy?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I use sqlalchemy `declarative_base` to create ORM models:

```py
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

Base = declarative_base()

class Model(Base):
    __tablename__ = "MODEL"
    FIRST_COL = Column(VARCHAR(length=255), primary_key=True)
```

Also i have to support several database providers. Previously it was just mssql and snowflake. I was able to use single declarative_base class for both providers(dialects took care of that). But now i have to support Firebolt as well. Firebolt has some non-typical for common sql database features(which help to store and manage big data). So i have to add `FireboltPartitionConstraint`(that is custom constraint) to a table in case of Firebolt. So i created a new class having the same table name, but with different **table_args**.

```py
class FireboltModel(Base):
    __tablename__ = "MODEL"
    FIRST_COL = Column(VARCHAR(length=255), primary_key=True)
    __table_args__ = (FireboltPartitionConstraint("BUS_TENANT_CODE", "BUS_ACCOUNT_CODE"),)
```

But now sqlalchemy gives me an error:
`sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: Table 'MODEL' is already defined for this MetaData instance.  Specify 'extend_existing=True' to redefine options and columns on an existing Table object.`

I've tried to use different declarative_base object for these classes, but it don't work:

```py
Base = declarative_base()

FireboltBase = declarative_base()
```

How can i bypass this error and implement strategy pattern in sqlalchemy to be able to use different model definitions for different database providers?